# Creating twitch irc bot (Login authentication failed)

Tags: python, python-2.7, bots, irc, twitch

I am using Python 2.7 and i'm trying to create IRC bot for twitch but i have a problem. I created bot in other IRC like "webchat.freenode.net" and everything was ok..My code for twitch :

```
import time
import socket


HOST = "irc.twitch.tv"
PORT = 6667
BOTNICK = "thebot"
PASSWORD = "oauth:nph788dap10fu6ozlzv1b32fzm4r8q"
CHAN = "#fordotis10"




irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect((HOST, PORT))
irc.setblocking(False)
time.sleep(1)

irc.send("PASS "+PASSWORD+"\r\n")

time.sleep(1)

irc.send("USER "+BOTNICK+" "+BOTNICK+" "+BOTNICK+" :I AM BOT!\r\n")

time.sleep(1)

irc.send("NICK "+BOTNICK+"\r\n")
time.sleep(1)

irc.send("JOIN "+CHAN+"\r\n")

text= ""
while 1:
    try:
        text = irc.recv(1024)
        print text
    except Exception:
        pass
    if text.find("PING")!=-1:
        irc.send("PONG "+text.split()[1]+"\r\n")
```

With this code , i get the following error:

:tmi.twitch.tv NOTICE * :Login authentication failed

What am i missing?

Comment: If it were something I was doing, I'd try to find something that's already working and compare the two.  Perhaps something like this would help?  https://github.com/aidanrwt/twitch-bot

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i use now http://pytwitcherapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and works!!

Comment: Feel free to write (and accept) your own answer for future readers!

Answer (score 1):

Finally , i found the problem with my code!! So, i will write the steps to create twitch bot with 2 ways!

**First way** :

1. You must create an account to twitch

   ```
   import socket
   import re


   HOST = "irc.twitch.tv"

   PORT = 6667

   NICK = "botname" #The account Name

   PASS = "The password here" #http://www.twitchapps.com/tmi/

   CHAN = "#Channel"


   s = socket.socket()

   s.connect((HOST, PORT))

   s.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(PASS))

   s.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(NICK))

   s.send("JOIN {}\r\n".format(CHAN))

   while True:
       resp = s.recv(1024)
       print resp
       if resp == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
           s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n")
       if resp.find("hi")!=-1:
           s.send("PRIVMSG "+CHAN+" :HELLO\r\n")


      resp = ""
   ```

**Second way** :

I found *pytwitcherapi*, You can read the documentation from : http://pytwitcherapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import pytwitcherapi
import time
import webbrowser
import threading
import queue

session = pytwitcherapi.TwitchSession()

url = session.get_auth_url()

session.start_login_server()

webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open(url) #OAuth generator

while not session.authorized:
    time.sleep(1)

time.sleep(2)

print "Authorized"

session.shutdown_login_server()

channel = session.get_channel("ChannelName")

client =  pytwitcherapi.IRCClient(session,channel)

t = threading.Thread(target = client.process_forever)
t.start()

print "connected"

while True:
    try:
        m = client.messages.get(False)
        if m.text == "!ping":
            client.send_msg("pong!")
        if m.text =="hey":
            client.send_msg("Hey You!")
    except queue.Empty:
         pass
```

Hope all this help you !!

Comment: update to this answer below (uses python 3 and doesnt give byte format errors

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell using [this](https://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc) page, `HOST = "irc.twitch.tv"` should be `HOST = irc.chat.twitch.tv"`.

Comment: I don't have anything to test this with, but maybe removing the `USER` message will work. I would also double-check the username and OAuth token for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to the answer above using Python 3 and correcting some byte format errors. Adapted from here:
https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/how-stream-text-data-twitch-sockets-python/

```
import socket
import re

server = 'irc.chat.twitch.tv'
port = 6667
nickname = 'my_twitch_name'
token = 'oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
channel = '#streamer_twitch_name'

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((server, port))
s.send(f"PASS {token}\n".encode('utf-8'))
s.send(f"NICK {nickname}\n".encode('utf-8'))
s.send(f"JOIN {channel}\n".encode('utf-8'))

while True:
    resp = s.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
    print(resp)
    # PING and PONG keep client active.
    if resp == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
        s.send(str("PRIVMSG "+channel+" :PONG\r\n").encode('utf-8'))
    if resp.find("hi")!=-1:
        s.send(str("PRIVMSG "+channel+" :HELLO\r\n").encode('utf-8'))
    resp = ""
    
s.close()
```